# Why is my Dart constructor returning a dynamic rather than typed object?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm parsing some JSON to read stored data into custom objects. I've implemented this simply using `jsonDecode` from dart:convert and writing a `fromJson()` constructor method on each of my custom objects. They're nested - so a `TopicList` object has a property which is a `List<Topic>`. I've written the `fromJson()` constructor on both `TopicList` and `Topic`, and I'm trying to use `map` to take the decoded JSON string and create an object from it. But it's failing because the list that map returns is of the wrong type, despite it being created from constructor methods.

```
class TopicList {
  List<Topic> topics;

  TopicList() {}

  TopicList.fromJson(String jsonTopicList) {
    Map decoded = jsonDecode(jsonTopicList);

// this *doesn't* work
    topics = decoded['topics'].map((t) => Topic.fromJson(t)).toList();

// this does work
    topics = [];
    for (Map<String,dynamic> t in decoded['topics']) {
      Topic newT = Topic.fromJson(t);
      topics.add(newT);
    }
  }
}

class Topic {
  String topic;

  Topic({this.topic});

  Topic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> t) {
    this.topic = t['topic'];
  }
}
```

When I try/catch the `map` method it tells me that the `map().toList()` call is returning a `List<dynamic>` rather than `List<Topic>`.

The reality is more complex than this with a further level (another `List` of other objects belonging to `Topic`) and with other properties. But this is the core of what is going on.

I'm not interested in workarounds - I've got one of those, which is working in the code above. But I want to understand why seemingly an object's constructor - in this example, it's `Topic.fromJson()` - is returning a dynamic object rather than a `Topic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a type argument to `.map()`.

```dart
topics = decoded['topics'].map<Topic>((t) => Topic.fromJson(t)).toList();
```

Comment: I've been working on this for 3 days. I've done explicit typecasting in a few ways, I've rearranged code, I've been through the debugger line by line watching as the correct type appears over and over only to be changed to List<dynamic> at the last second and throw an error.  And nothing worked until this.  Thank you!

Comment: I had the same miserable experience for the past three days too. Can anybody point me to some docs or videos that help explain this topic. I would really like to understand why this fixes the issue better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
topics = decoded['topics'].map((t) => Topic.fromJson(t)).toList();
```

to

```
topics = decoded['topics'].map<Topic>((t) => Topic.fromJson(t)).toList();
```

That way, `map` will return an iterator of `Topic` which `toList` will convert to a list.

Comment: Tried all kinds of places to put that type argument ... except there! Thanks